# Copiar un archivo.txt que no existe de un directorio a otro

Tags: cmd

Tengo que copiar un **archivo.txt** que no existe en

```
C:\Users\Desktop\COPIA a "C:\Users\Desktop"
```

He usado XCOPY para crear un archivo en un directorio que no existe **(XCOPY /I)** pero no encuentro ninguna opción que permita crear y copiar a la vez un archivo a un directorio.
¿Es posible hacerlo con XCOPY?

Comment: Con no existe, ¿te refieres que no existe en la carpeta de destino? ¿que contiene el archivo? ¿O simplemente lo quieres vacío?
¿Vas a teclear tú la copia o lo haces desde un .bat?

Comment: Con no existe me refiero a que en la carpeta COPIA que es desde donde tengo que copiar el archivo, no existe ningún archivo es una carpeta vacía. EL ejercicio me pide que copie un archivo que no existe en la carpeta COPIA al Desktop. [Copie un archivo que no existe de la ubicación COPIA al escritorio. NOTA : que no se te olvide la extensión.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opción 1: Creando el fichero con texto dentro escrito por ti:

```
copy con C:\Users\Desktop\archivo.txt

"hola esto es el contenido del archivo"
[CONTROL]+[Z] [ENTER]

xcopy C:\Users\Desktop\archivo.txt C:\Users\Desktop\COPIA\archivo.txt /v /f
```

Opción 2: Creando un fichero vacío:

```
aaa > C:\Users\Desktop\archivo.txt

xcopy C:\Users\Desktop\archivo.txt C:\Users\Desktop\COPIA\archivo.txt /v /f
```